# Extract the key names from a fixed JSON structure

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON with dynamic data and not sure how I can retrieve data with JQ.
My JSON is:

```json
{
   "RuntimeSources":{
      "env-name-DYNAMIC":{
         "the-dynamic-value-i-need-to-get":{
            "url":""
         }
      }
   },
   "DeploymentId":147,
   "Serial":158
}
```

'env-name-DYNAMIC' is dynamic and 'the-dynamic-value-i-need-to-get' is the same.
The json structure is always the same. How can I get 'the-dynamic-value-i-need-to-get'? Also I may need to retrieve 'env-name-DYNAMIC'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `keys[]` attribute

```
.RuntimeSources | keys[]
```

and also

```
.RuntimeSources | keys[] as $k | .[$k] | keys[]
```

Since you had also mentioned, the structure doesn't change, you can just select the paths that contains 3 levels

```
paths | select( length == 3 ) | .[1]
paths | select( length == 3 ) | .[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it with:

```
jq '.RuntimeSources | .[] | keys'
```

Not sure if it's the best solution, but did the trick.